# Calling asp.net asmx webservice via ajax returns 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, asmx, http-status-code-401

There's an asmx:

```
[WebService]
[ScriptService]
public class MyService : WebService {
    [WebMethod]
    public OperationResult Validate(string str) { }
}
```

There's a **https**://.../a.aspx, in this page, I call the webserivce via jQuery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Services/MyService.asmx/Validate',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: data,
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        // xxx
    }
});
```

Note that a.aspx are using **HTTPS**. The ajax request will get a 401 Unauthorized response.
If a.aspx is not using HTTPS, it works.

I'm using a library named "WebPageSecurity", if I use it, the 401 error will happen. If I don't use it, that is, direct entery https://.../a.aspx in browser, then it will work.
So I guess the problem in in the WebPageSecurity, how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I found the solution: Ignore the *.asmx file in WebPageSecurity configuration in web.config:

```
  <secureWebPages mode="On" ignoreHandlers="WithStandardExtensions" encryptedUri="xxx">
    <files>
      <add path="path/to/MyService.asmx/MyMethod" secure="Ignore" />
    </files>
  </secureWebPages>
```

Comment: I know it's not recent but does this cause any security issues?